# Return zero records when one value in "WHERE IN (..)" is not found

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query that does something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Id IN (574,575,576,577,578,579,580)
```

This query returns all the records that it can find with one of those seven `ID`s. If it can't find one of those ID's then it will simply return less records.

What I actually need is that it either returns ALL records, or NONE.

So if it can't find one of the ID's present in the `IN` clause, then it should return zero records.

I'm building a dynamic query against a view, so I can ONLY add custom queries after the `WHERE` clause.

How can I do this in one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an odd request.  But it sounds like you want a non-correlated subquery to count the ids:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where Id in (574, 575, 576, 577, 578, 579, 580) and
      7 = (select count(distinct id)
           from mytable
           where Id in (574, 575, 576, 577, 578, 579, 580)
          );
```

You might not actually want to repeat the values, so:

```
with t as (
      select t.*
      from mytable t
      where Id in (574, 575, 576, 577, 578, 579, 580)
    )
select t.*
from t
where 7 = (select count(distinct id) from t);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some fancy joining if you put the values into a table variable

```
DECLARE @list table(id int)
INSERT @list values(1),(574),(575),(576),(577),(578),(579),(580)
-- remarked row
--INSERT @list values(574),(575),(576),(577),(578),(579),(580)

DECLARE @mytable table(id int)

INSERT @mytable values(574),(575),(576),(577),(578),(579),(580),(581),(592)

SELECT mt.* FROM
  @myTable mt
JOIN @list list on mt.id = list.id
WHERE not exists(SELECT id from @list EXCEPT SELECT id from @myTable)
```

Result 0 rows returned.

7 rows will be returned if you used the remarked row as testdata instead